# Arrays multiplication in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the error message "'Float' object is not

subscriptable"

```
import stdio

import stdarray

n = 3

x = [0.30, 0.60, 0.10]

y = [0.40, 0.10, 0.50]

c = stdarray.create2D(n, n, 0.0)

for i in range(n):

    for j in range(n):

        c[i][j] += x[i][j] * y[i][j]

        stdio.writeln(c)
```

Comment: What do you expect `x[i][j]` and `y[i][j]` to be?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. What is your question? Stack Overflow is not a free debugging service, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays x and y are 1d arrays, you can index them as if they are 2d arrays.
I think you wanted to index x by i and y by j.
Try

```
import stdio

import stdarray

n = 3

x = [0.30, 0.60, 0.10]

y = [0.40, 0.10, 0.50]

c = stdarray.create2D(n, n, 0.0)

for i in range(n):

    for j in range(n):

        c[i][j] += x[i] * y[j]

        stdio.writeln(c)
```